# Accessing ruby variables in nested objects

Tags: ruby, variables, scope

I have a gem that I am working on.  In it is an executable that parses a Config file and then instantiates a couple of objects.  One of these objects then instantiates a number of "handler" objects.  I am parsing the config file into an array, `CONFIG`, but the settings within are not accessible in any of the other objects.  They are needed in the handlers.  When I try to use them, the variable does not exist.

I understand that this is a variable scope issue.  However I am not sure what I need to do to make these accessible throughout the entire program (including sub/nested objects) and not just the initial executable.  While each of the objects in the program are within a module, the actions in the executable are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are global, but they live in the namespace in which they are defined.

If you define `CONFIG` in the main context, it will be global at the root-level. If you define it in a class or module, you must refer to it by its full name outside of that context.

For example:

```
class Foo
  CONFIG = File.read(...)
end

CONFIG # => Error, not defined
Foo::CONFIG # => Defined
```

It's generally bad form to reference constants by name, they run against the grain of proper object-oriented design. As such, if you define constants, they should be used internally only, and exposed via methods that sub-classes can redefine or patch as required.

A better example:

```
class Foo
  CONFIG = File.read(...)

  def self.config
    CONFIG
  end
end

Foo.config # => Your configuration
```

This simple abstraction is important because a sub-class can re-define your configuration:

```
class Bar < Foo
  def self.config
    # ... Different implementation
  end
end

Bar.config # => Different result
```

Even better is to avoid constants altogether and simply lazy-load things as required:

```
class Foo
  def self.config
    @config ||= File.read(...)
  end
end

Foo.config # => Your configuration
```

Constants are best reserved for things that do not change, like `SEPARATOR = ':'`, where it's not possible or practical to reconfigure them without breaking a lot of code.

Where you have something that's read in from an external source, where it might vary based on configuration or preference, it's usually more convenient to have a method that intermediates this.

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer and gives me a lot of insight as to the scope of things.  Ruby is my first go at anything object oriented.  In this case, I am loading the config in the "main" part of the code, outside of any class.  Do I need to move the config into its own class, or is there some other "Good" way to do this in that context?

Comment: Having the config in its own class makes it a lot easier to test, so it's probably a good idea. It's also nice when the config itself is contained in a tidy structure rather than being strewn around in dozens of independent variables.